# VIM: Hyphen in ruler column value

Tags: linux, vim

I have the ruler turned on in vim but the column value is two numbers separated by a hyphen. e.g. 1-8.

[image]

What exactly does a hyphenated column value mean in vim?

Comment: Where exactly is this `column value`? A variable? A number displayed by vim status bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `:h ruler`

The relavent section is copied below

```
If the number of characters displayed is different from the number of
bytes in the text (e.g., for a TAB or a multi-byte character), both
the text column (byte number) and the screen column are shown,
separated with a dash.
```

Explanation of `1,1-8`

The first 1 is that the cursor is on line 1. The 1-8 means that your cursor is on the first text column (ie the first character in the string) and that it is the 8th visual column. Therefore we can conclude that your cursor is on a tab where your tabstop, and shiftwidth are set to 8.